# как сохранить словарь в csv в каждой строке, у меня получается через строку когда открываю через Excel

Tags: python, парсер, csv

как сохранить словарь в csv в каждой строке, у меня получается через строку когда открываю через Excel

```
def write():
    with open(f"{CATEGORY}.csv", mode="a", newline='', encoding='utf-8') as w_file:
        names = ["Наименование", "Наличие_на_складе", "Код товара", "Стоимость"]
        file_writer = csv.DictWriter(w_file, delimiter=";", fieldnames=names)
        file_writer.writeheader()
        for i in range(len(DATA)):
            item = DATA[i]
            file_writer.writerow(item)
    print(f"{CATEGORY}.csv записан!")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что у вас в `DATA`?

Comment: данные ["Наименование", "Наличие","Код товара","Цена"]